# How can I make an array dynamically in php?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

In the below code the repetition of foreach is unknown. It depends on database records.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
        foreach ($get_all_users as $row){                    
                echo $name[$i] = $row->name;
                $i++;
        }
?>
```

Now, in below, I want to make an array dynamically, as many as foreach repetition. But I can't add any loops into array:

```
$i = 0;
$data['name'] = array (                     
    $i => $name[$i],                     
);
```

Actually, I need something like this: (of course it's impossible)

```
$i = 0;
$data['name'] = array (
    for(...)                    
    $i => $name[$i],
);
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't got your point. Are yoy trying to populate an array within a foreach? Did you try `array_push()`?

Comment: It's very possible to build an array in a foreach loop, but I have no idea what you're asking for.  Can you please try to reword your post, clearly stating your goal and your question?

Comment: Be careful with your assignment and equality. $name[$i] = $row->name; just because it's in an echo doesn't mean it won't assign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**
Attending your comment...

```
$data['name'] = array(); 
foreach($get_all_users as $row){ 
    array_push($data['name'], $row->name);
}
```

Comment: but I have to use like this: $data['name']
because I want to accsess in view for $name
I use codeigniter.

Comment: @vahidnajafi Do you need an array of names, inside `$data['name']`?

Comment: @vahidnajafi No problem! The function `array_push` doesn't need to know your array size. It just pushes new values to the end of the `$data['names']` array.

Comment: Thank you very much.
It's exactly my answer.
So sorry, I can't vote.
Again thank you.

Comment: @vahidnajafi You're welcome! Up vote my answer and try to accept as answer clicking in the "check" icon.

Comment: I can't vote up due to my less reputation. I'll vote up as soon as possible.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define an blank array and then put values into it with empty "index".

Something like this:

```
$names = array();
foreach ($get_all_users as $row){                    
  $names[] = $row->name;
}
```

Comment: but I have to use like thie: $data['name']
because I want to accsess in view for $name
I use codeigniter

Comment: @vahidnajafi so use that? It doesn't change the answer

Comment: You can use $names[]['name'] - this will create new element with numeric index but you can iterate through it and access it with 'name' identifier.

Comment: If you do that, you'd have to iterate over the whole array and test each element to see if the name matched.  Better to use name as the index.  At least then if you know the name you can access it directly.

Comment: You are correct and then the answer from user3980820 is more on point of what was needed here - the question was a bit vague (at least to me :))

Comment: No, I think I can't access to $name with array $names[]['name'].
If can't understand what I mean exactly, look at to the first answer. (UPDATE part)
Again thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to use two loops only one like this :

```
$data['name'] = array();

foreach ($get_all_users as $row){                    
            $data['name'][] = $row->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

```
$data = array_column($get_all_users, 'name');
```

is what you need. It's a little unclear....